# How to evaluate javascript predefined function in angular expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression

I want to evaluate some js predefined function in angular expression. For example `new Date()`. But, not able to do that. If it is possible, please explain how to do that.

For example:

```
<input type="text" ng-init="yearFromSelector=new Date().getFullYear()"  ng-model="yearFromSelector">
```

or

```
{{new Date().getFullYear()}}
```

I know that we can do that in controller and send value to view using `$scope`. But, I want to know is it possible to do it in angular expressions itself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show, the code of your controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can't construct instances in Angular expressions. You will need to use some controller code:

```
ng-init="yearFromSelector = getDate().getFullYear()"
```

where you would need to define `getDate` helper function either in controller or globally in `run` block (and attach it to `$rootScope`):

```
$scope.getDate = function() {
  return new Date
}
```

Read about what Angular expression allow and what do not: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: Yeah, I have already tried the same using controller. But, I want to know how to do it in expression itself if possible.